# Android ID change after update android OS 9 to 10 or above?

Tags: android, android-identifiers

I'm on progress proving Android ID only changing when factory reset happen on OS 9, OS 10 and above.

using this code :

```
@SuppressLint("HardwareIds")
    override fun getAndroidId(): String? {
        return try {
            Settings.Secure.getString(context.contentResolver, Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Stump.e(TAG, "error get android_id $e")
            null
        }
    }
```

One of the scenario test that I still can't complete is :
`Android os 9 update to 10 or above`

Tldr;
I tried updating OS in real devices but still failed :

1. Samsung A20S current Binary : U3 - not found same binary file to upgrade into
2. Samsung S9 current Binary : U8 - not found same binary file to upgrade into

One that worked is :
3. **Xiaomi Mi A1 OS 9 update to PixelExperience OS 11, this shows that the android ID changed, but I don't think the way I test it is correct.**

I've read this similar question : [Does android device id changes on android version update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30572953/does-android-device-id-changes-on-android-version-update) the accepted answer is in 2015 says no, but in the accepted comment's answer saying that it's indeed changing when os update, so I was confused which one is true.

Please help answer is Android ID change after update android OS 9 to 10 or above ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get unique device id in android 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60501286/how-can-i-get-unique-device-id-in-android-10)

Comment: Maybe Find a Solution below link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/70459287/13634409